# WebAPI returning 404s in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I know this question has ***plenty*** of other questions that on the face of it may seem the same but I'm fairly sure my case is slightly different. I'm getting 404 errors on our production environment for an API call and I have tried all of the following:

- `<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
   <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" path="*" verb="*"               type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>`
- `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`
- `<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`

Having looked at most of the potential solutions online, I found that most peoples error messages were this:

[image: Error]

Where mine differs is the *Handler* part in the left column. Mine instead mentions the `System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler` which suggests its hitting something relating to the API.

The URL I'm trying to hit is https://website.com/api/discounts/validate and my routes are configured as so:

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiDefault",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

And `Register` is called from my `Global.asax.cs` at the very end of the `Application_Start` method. Again, this all works in our development and QA environments.

Comment: Make sure you're pointing it into the right path in IIS.

Comment: @OrelEraki Could you expand?

Comment: @jumpingcode Is this happening in GET operation as well?

Comment: @AllanT The request above is [HttpGet]